# Is it decidable that $A^nx=B^mx$ for some $n,m\geq1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Let $A$ and $B$ be $k\times k$ matrices with integer coefficients and $x \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ be a fixed vector.

Is there and algorithm to determine if there exist $n, m \geq 1$ satisfying $A^nx = B^mx$?

Such an algorithm would be very useful for a problem in which I am working on.
Unfortunately, I don't have much intuition about its existence.

In my case, $A$, $B$ and $x$ have positive entries, but I suspect that this is not relevant.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, you could probably use the decomposition of $x$ into sums of eigenvectors of $A,B$ respectively and compare to see if there's a possible match.  Otherwise, if they're not diagonalizable or if you want to avoid the possibility of rounding errors in floating point arithmetic giving a false negative, you might be able to use the cyclic decomposition and do something vaguely similar.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Wouldn't we need that $A$ and $B$ are *simultaneously* diagonalizable in order to compare the coefficients of the decompositions in eigenvectors?

Comment: If the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ don't match, then yes, that would make it more difficult to try to match the two sides.

Comment: Equivalent is that $A^n-B^m$ is singular and that $x$ is an eigenvector to eigenvalue $0$ , but I am not sure whether that helps. Like the mortality problem , this might be undecidable. But maybe, I overlook something.

Comment: It doesn't have to be diagonalizable, you can look up it's Jordan normal form and compare the eigenvalues's in the form.